# How do I use jQuery in firefox addon?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

I want to use jQuery in the sidebar of my firefox extension. This is how I include jQuery in the sidebar.xul

```
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://myaddon/content/
  scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

First question, why do we use the `jQuery.noConflict()` function?

I tried the solutions of some other questions but it did not work for me.

Still this does not work for me on FF 3.6.13:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" 
       src="chrome://myextension/content/scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: And yours is working or not? Or is your only question about `noConflict`?

Comment: I want to now the basic approach how to use jQuery in a firefox extension, I played with it a bit but I just do not know where to put the js/jquery code and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include other libraries like prototype, mootools, YUI etc, The problem comes when one or more of those libraries are used with jQuery as they also use $() as their global function and to define variables. This situation creates conflict as $() is used by jQuery and other library as their global function. To overcome from such situations, jQuery has introduced jQuery.noConflict().

So you can basically do

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can write jQuery command using `$j()` instead of `$()`

As for the firefox plugin, I'm assuming you are referring to firebug. The area where you type in your jquery is called console.  You can read more at http://getfirebug.com/commandline

[image]

Comment: thanks, but where does this code go? where do I have to put it? if I put this in my sidebar.xul it has no effect

Comment: @ArtWorkAD The link i provided should have helped you out. I updated the post above and included a screen-shot. Click on the console tab, then click on the bottom right icon to toggle the area where you type in area to show either on the right side or bottom.

Comment: thanks but this does not solve my problem, firebug gives either null or undefined when I execute some jquery

Comment: @ArtWorkAD you are asking multiple things in one question. i gave you the answer for both `jQuery.noConflict` and also showed you were to type your jQuery. If you are having problems with console not responding to your jQuery commands, consider accepting this answer start another question. This issue is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Hussein - I'm very confused. What does your screen capture have to do with the question asked?

Comment: @iwburk, this question is 2 month old, if i remember correctly OP didn't know where to enter the jQuery code in console (guess he meant firebug). The screenshot shows console and where to type code. You can Ignore the code inside console.

Answer (score 1):

Does this alert `hello`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

If it does, then jQuery is working. This seems like really trivial answer, sorry.

Comment: I've successfully used `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` like Hussein says below. Try it, it goes inside your `script type="text/javascript">` tag like above.

Comment: I have updated my question, jquery seems to be successfully loaded, but there is no alert..