# Firefox 3.6 Addon Developement: including jquery in XUL template makes Webdeveloper toolbar unstable

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, xul, web-developer-toolbar

i'm developing a Firefox Extensions. I've included in one of mine xul jquery. Now, i'm noticed that , in Firefox 3.6, jquery makes Webdeveloper Toolbar unstable. It disappear!

I've have already tested the `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` solution but it doesn't helps me.

Some other solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use jQuery 1.5.2+ on a Firefox addon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863557/how-can-i-use-jquery-1-5-2-on-a-firefox-addon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been around for a while - there's discussion on the [webdev toolbar forums](http://chrispederick.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=2374) and a [jquery bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4443) - there are various suggestions for workarounds, one of which may work for you.

Comment: this helps, thanks                                                                                                           window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
      (function(loader){
          loader.loadSubScript("chrome://{app-name}/content/jquery-1.3.2.js");
      })(
          Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(
              Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader
          )
      );
  //Your code goes
  }, false);